# Caculated Column Help

Tags: 2010, column

I am trying to use a calculated column to generate something like this using [Created]:
161000TAPR15

16=Day of the Week,
10=Hour,
00=Minutes,
T=[TimeZone],First letter of the Time Zone,
APR=Month,
15=Year,

I've tried various combinations and nothing seems to work. Please help!

Comment: Is your Day, Hour, Minutes, TimeZone, etc. all in different columns? Or do you want to take the default "Created" field and format it like `161000TAPR15`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: I deleted my previous answer because I realized I had included the "minutes" portion incorrectly. Sorry for any confusion, I'm still new here.

This solution uses a "helper" `TimeZone` column. So you will need to select a time zone for each item uploaded. The `TimeZone` column is a choice column with the time zone choices (i.e. Pacific, Mountain, Central, Eastern, whatever you want).

Next, create a `CalDate` calculated column with the following formula, which uses the default `Created` column to pull the date values with the following formula:

`=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Created,"dd"),TEXT(Created,"hmm"),LEFT(TimeZone,1),TEXT(Created,"mmm"),TEXT(Created,"yy"))`

And here is the result:

[image: The results]

And you can change the month to all uppercase by using this formula:

`=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Created,"dd"),TEXT(Created,"hmm"),LEFT(TimeZone,1),UPPER(TEXT(Created,"mmm")),TEXT(Created,"yy"))`

[image: with uppercase]

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter and easier to read:

```
=UPPER(REPLACE(TEXT(Created,"ddhhmmTZmmmyy"),7,2,LEFT(TimeZone))
```

- SharePoint REPLACE (alas) needs a start and length parameter
  TZ starts at character 7 and is 2 characters long
- LEFT() takes 1 character by default